# Problem with graphing equation in polar form vs Cartesian form

Tags: calculus, functions, graphing-functions, polar-coordinates

I was trying to graph Lituus using polar equation $r^2 \theta=a$ 
Here $a$ is a constant.
But when I try to convert it into Cartesian equation the graph looks bizarre.
$$y=x \tan(\frac{a}{(x^2+y^2}))$$
.
Can anyone explain this, why is it happening?
Here is pictures
[image: with polar equation]
.
.
[image: with Cartesian equation]

Answer (score 1):

The function $$\tan (\frac {a}{x^2+y^2})$$ is undefined for points where $$ \frac {a}{x^2+y^2}= (2k+1)\pi /2$$

Which makes your graph missing some points.

Note that the two equations are not exactly the same because of asymptotic behavior of the tangent function.